# Python RegEx not returning correct value. Not sure where I am going wrong here

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to build a PO BOX validator. I have tested the regular expression on several sites so I know it works. But for some reason I cant get it to work in python.

```
m = re.compile('/\b(?:p\.?\s*o\.?|post\s+office)(\s+)?(?:box|[0-9]*)?\b/gi')
print(m.match('PO BOX'))
```

Comment: are you aware that `/` is a real `/` on python regex engine? this isn't `sed`

Comment: your expression starts with `/` and you try to match (not _search_) `PO`, so that just cannot match, _ever_

Comment: and even without those, it just doesn't match...

Comment: Ok so should I escape the / ? Sorry a bit of a noob

Answer (score 2):

you may have tried your expression on `sed`-like engines but python regular expressions don't start with `/` unless you want to match `/`

your expression starts with `/` and you try to match (not *search*) `PO`, so that just cannot match, *ever*

Same goes for `/gi` in the end (but you have to set the `re.IGNORECASE` as regex flags).

Other issue is that `\b` needs escaping (else it's interpreted as *backspace*).

Using raw string prefix allows to avoid that explicit escaping. That works, at least for `PO BOX` string:

```
m =re.compile(r'\b(?:p\.?\s*o\.?|post\s+office)(\s+)?(?:box|[0-9]*)?\b',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(m.match("PO BOX"))
```

prints:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='PO BOX'>
```